# Vue js: mapping array from API response data to checkbox list and back

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue js to display and edit details of a person. The person being edited has a list of favourite colours that I want to display as a list of checkboxes. When I change the colours selected, and click the 'Update' button, the person object should be updated accordingly, so I can pass back to the api to update.

I've got as far as displaying the Person object's colours correctly against their respective checkboxes. But I'm struggling with passing the changes to the colour selection, back to the Person object. Below is my checkbox list and details of how I've tried to implement this. Is there a better way of doing this?

[image]

I've tried using 'b-form-checkbox-group'. Below is my code.
Please note - The list of available colours is dynamic, but I've temporarily hardcoded a list of colours ('colourData') till I get this working.
Also, in the 'UpdatePerson' method, I've commented out my attempts to get the selected colours mapped back to the Person object.

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="updatePerson">
  
      <b-form-group label="Favourite colours:">
          <b-form-checkbox-group id="favColours"
                                 v-model="colourSelection"
                                 :options="colourOptions"
                                 value-field="item"
                                 text-field="name">

          </b-form-checkbox-group>
      </b-form-group>
      
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <b-btn type="submit" variant="success">Save Record</b-btn>
      </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
    import service from '@/api-services/colours.service'

    export default {
        name: 'EditPersonData',
        data() {
            return {
                personData: {
                    personId: '',
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: '',
                    colours:[]
                },
                colourData: [
                    { colourId: '1', isEnabled: '1', name: 'Red' },
                    { colourId: '2', isEnabled: '1', name: 'Green' },
                    { colourId: '3', isEnabled: '1', name: 'Blue' },
                ],
                selectedColours: [],
                colourSelection: []
            };
        },
        computed: {
            colourOptions: function () {
                return this.colourData.map(v => {
                    let options = {};
                    options.item = v.name;
                    options.name = v.name;
                    return options;
                })
            }
        },
        created() {
            service.getById(this.$route.params.id).then((response) => {
                this.personData = response.data;
                this.colourSelection = response.data.colours.map(function (v) { return v.name; });
                this.selectedColours = response.data.colours;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.response.data);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            async updatePerson() {                
                //const cs = this.colourSelection;
                //const cd = this.colourData.filter(function (elem) {
                //    if (cs.indexOf(elem.name) != -1) { return elem;}
                //});
                //this.personData.colours = [];
                //this.personData.colours = cd;

                service.update(this.$route.params.id, this.personData).then(() => {
                    this.personData = {};
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help wold be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by making the below changes to the commented part in the 'updatePerson()' method:

```vue
methods: {
    async updatePerson() {
        const cs = this.colourSelection;
        const cd = this.colourData.filter(function (elem) {
            if (cs.some(item => item === elem.name)) { return elem; }
        });
        this.personData.colours = [];
        this.personData.colours = cd;
        service.update(this.$route.params.id, this.personData).then(() => {
            this.personData = {};
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    }
}
```